# Browsers (IE, Chrome, new installed Firefox) not displaying most pages

Tags: windows-7, networking, google-chrome, firefox, browser

### TL;DR

Windows 7 x64 all browsers (even fresh installed) don't render almost any page. But network traffic is fine (http 200ok payload correct), no proxy, no malware etc.
started occuring after windows update ~1.5 week ago

---

Hi,

my father called me last week with a really interesting phenominal. At first I thought it was a normal problem by configuring something he shouldn't do.

But checking his computer (windows 7 x64 with current updates) the following phenomen is active:

Most of the pages we would like to browse to using a browser (IE 10, current Chrome) will not display the pages. But some do work - I was able to load google and search - but was not able to open any search results.

I downloaded then a fresh firefox installation but also the same result. There is no proxy in any way configured. The network settings are correct I checked them in many different ways.

Receiving data from the internet works very well. I can ping the whole world without any problems, I can even download data like a Windows Update or like the mentioned firefox setup.

I was also able to browse to wireshark.org and download it.
I checked the network traffic and I can see that HTTP traffic really does what it should in  the background.

DNS gets resolved correct, HTTP Request is sent and HTTP 200 OK is received. I can even see the html in the payload and it is complete. But still all browsers just look like they are still loading the webpage and nothing is displayed.

I am really crazy about this problem as I can not figure out what is the problem. Some rare sites really work (google.de, wireshark.org, mozilla.org) but nearly everything else fails, but the network traffic the computer sends and receives is correct and complete.

My father reported that everything was fine until some day after he installed some windows updates. He even told me that he once set Windows back to the time the updates were installed and it worked. After shutting down and automatical install of the updates same behaviour is back again.
I have not yet checked the log which windows update in that time period is installed but if anybody has any advice or has heard of such a problem I am glad for hints and what to do.

Regards,
Stefan

Comment: Which version of windows? Do you know what date it started happening (the approximate date of the updates)?

Comment: @DavidPostill I updated the question with a TL;DR and your asked information so you can directly view them.

Comment: Sound like it was one of patches in [Patch Tuesday March 2015](https://community.qualys.com/blogs/laws-of-vulnerabilities/2015/03/10/patch-tuesday-march-2015) but which one :/